# object with multiple instances with internal data store separate for each instance

Tags: library

I'm trying to keep track of a timer, and the internal variables seem to be overrun by one another.

I just want two instances of the Output class, which can keep track of the _elapsed_time so I can check if the time elapsed. It's a poor-man's real-time for a game. I know there are libraries available and I'm planning to use them, but I would really appreciate knowing what's going on here: I want a buzzer pin, and status led pin to 'blink' at different intervals. They both work individually, but when I have them both uncommented they work somewhat serially...

```
#include "Arduino.h"

#include "MTC.h"

#include <SoftwareSerial.h>   //Software Serial Port

//HARDWARE SETTINGS
#define PIN_STATUS                  13
#define PIN_BUZZER                  A2

Output *STATUS(0);
Output *BUZZER;

void setup()
{
    Serial.begin(9600);
    STATUS = new Output();
    STATUS->Begin(PIN_STATUS, STATE_OFF);
    BUZZER = new (Output) Output(3);
    BUZZER->Begin(PIN_BUZZER, STATE_OFF);
}

void loop()
{
    static bool run_once = true;

    if (run_once == true)
    {
        run_once = false;
        Serial.print("Running");
        Serial.flush();
    }
    delay(250);

    //Serial.println("still running");

    STATUS->SetStrobe(3000);

    //BUZZER->SetStrobe(4000);

}
```

and class:

```
#ifndef MTC_h
#define MTC_H


typedef int OUTPUT_STATE;
OUTPUT_STATE STATE_OFF = 0;
OUTPUT_STATE STATE_ON = 1;
OUTPUT_STATE STATE_STROBE = 2;

class Output
{
private:
    int _pin;
    OUTPUT_STATE _last_state;
    unsigned long _cycle_duration;
        unsigned long _last_elapsed;

public:
    Output();                                           //constructor: set pin data store
    void Begin(int pin, OUTPUT_STATE state);                                //set hardware to output and defaul state
    void Set(OUTPUT_STATE state);                               //toggle operability
    void SetStrobe(unsigned long duration);                     //strobe operability
};

Output::Output()                                    //constructor: set pin data store
{

}

void Output::Begin(int pin, OUTPUT_STATE state)
{
    _pin = pin;
        _last_elapsed = millis();
    pinMode(_pin, OUTPUT);
    digitalWrite(_pin, state);
    _last_state = state;
}

void Output::Set(OUTPUT_STATE state)
{
    if (_last_state != state)
    {
        digitalWrite(_pin, state);
        _last_state = state;
    }
}

void Output::SetStrobe(unsigned long duration)
{
    static OUTPUT_STATE _last_strobe_state = STATE_OFF;

    unsigned long elapsed = millis() - _last_elapsed;
    if (elapsed >= duration)
    {
        if (_last_strobe_state == STATE_OFF)
        {
            digitalWrite(_pin, STATE_ON);
            _last_strobe_state = STATE_ON;
        }
        else
        {
            digitalWrite(_pin, STATE_OFF);
            _last_strobe_state = STATE_OFF;
        }
        _last_state = STATE_STROBE;
        _last_elapsed = millis();
    }
}
#endif
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `Output::SetStrobe()` is wrong, it uses a `static` variable (`_lasr_strobe_state`) that is thus shared between all instances of `OUTPUT`, which is NOT what you want.

You have to change it into a non-static member of class Output instead:

```
class Output
{
private:
    int _pin;
    OUTPUT_STATE _last_state;
    // NEW member here!!!
    OUTPUT_STATE _last_strobe_state;
    unsigned long _cycle_duration;
        unsigned long _last_elapsed;

public:
    Output();     //constructor: set pin data store
    void Begin(int pin, OUTPUT_STATE state);//set hardware to output and defaul state
    void Set(OUTPUT_STATE state);            //toggle operability
    void SetStrobe(unsigned long duration);  //strobe operability
};
```

Then you initialize it in the constructor:

```
Output::Output():_last_strobe_state(STATE_OFF)
{

}
```

And you remove it (static declaration) from method `SetProbe` (the rest of the method does not change):

```
void Output::SetStrobe(unsigned long duration)
{
    unsigned long elapsed = millis() - _last_elapsed;
    if (elapsed >= duration)
    {
        if (_last_strobe_state == STATE_OFF)
        {
            digitalWrite(_pin, STATE_ON);
            _last_strobe_state = STATE_ON;
        }
        else
        {
            digitalWrite(_pin, STATE_OFF);
            _last_strobe_state = STATE_OFF;
        }
        _last_state = STATE_STROBE;
        _last_elapsed = millis();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not a real answer, as @jfpoilpret already gave a perfectly valid
one. Just a few observations and suggestions from looking at your code.
I write is as an answer only because it is too long to fit in a comment.

1. The member variable `_cycle_duration` is not used. You could remove
   it and save a couple of bytes per Output instance.
2. `if (run_once == true)` is equivalent to `if ((run_once == true) ==
   true)`. They are both considered bad style. Preferred style is to
   just write `if (run_once)`.
3. On the Arduino, it is generally good practice to avoid dynamic
   allocation whenever possible. Of course, it is not always possible,
   but in this instance it is quite easy: declare STATUS and BUZZER as
   objects instead of pointers (as in `Output STATUS;`), then replace
   `->` by a single dot (`.`).